# iOS 16 - How to include more than 1 AppIntent / AppShortcut

Tags: swiftui, appintents, app-shortcut

I've implemented 2 different AppIntents, each includes their own AppShortcutsProvider with phrases unique to each AppIntent.  Individually, they work great.  But, when I try to include both in my app, only the last one defined works.

In my ContentView.onAppear(), I've tried calling:

```
ShortcutsOne.updateAppShortcutParameters()
ShortcutsTwo.updateAppShortcutParameters()
```

and only those defined in ShortcutsTwo are recognized by Siri.

I've tried including ShortcutsTwo's AppShortcut(intent:, phrases) in ShortcutOne's AppShortcutsProvider (since it's static var appShortcuts: is defined as an array, ie, [Shortcuts] - but that doesn't work either.

Overall, I've found the system to be rather temperamental.  ie, I have had to power off my iPhone & reboot my Mac to get changes recognized.

Any thoughts on how to get 2 or more AppIntents to work in one app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I’ve found 2 things of interest.

1. You CAN define 2 `AppShortcuts(intent:)` - but they CAN NOT have `[]`s around them nor commas separating them:

```
static var appShortcuts: [AppShortcut] {
  AppShortcut(intent:IntentOne(), phrases: [“phrase 1”])
  AppShortcut(intent:IntentTwo(), phrases: [“phrase 2”])
}
```

2. While developing, other devices that are listening to Siri but which do NOT have the current `AppShortcuts` defined will royally mess with your head. Turn off other devices until you’ve finished debugging your `AppIntents`!